# 3.5 D&D Mystic Theurge Specialist Wizard banned spells

Tags: dnd-3.5e, wizard, cleric, prestige-class

If one is playing a Mystic Theurge in 3.5 and the Wizard side has school specialization, would the banned schools also be affected on the cleric side.  If you had banned Enchantment and Illusion would Divine spells of Enchantment and Illusion also be banned - Thanks

Comment: To confirm: you are asking about D&D 3.5e right? If so, please add the [dnd-3.5e] tag to confirm (or the appropriate one for the system you are playing). Feel free to ask if you are uncertain or have any questions about the site (use @ to ping someone).